# Multiple ranges of numpy array returned

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

Suppose there is an array like the below:

```
a = np.array([[1,2],
              [2,3],
              [2,3],
              [2,3],
              [4,5],
              [3,4],
              [2,3]])
```

How would I return multiple rows, this is what I would like to achieve (I know the syntax is wrong, but this will give you an idea of what I want to achieve):

```
a[0:2 & 5:6,:]
```

I would not be able to pass individual rows because in my actual code I would need to include larger ranges, e.g. `20:60` & `90:160`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> a[np.r_[:2, 5:6], :]
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4]])
```

The [`np.r_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

> Translates slice objects to concatenation along the first axis.