# How do i select array specific ranges?

Tags: python

[image]

I want to select range in array like image.

If there is 12X8 array A, i want to select A[0~3,9~12][4,5] and change to 0.

So i wrote code like `A[[:3,8:],4:5] = 0`, but it occurred error.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution with numpy,

```
import numpy as np
A = np.ones((12,8))
A[np.r_[0:4,8:12],3:5] = 0
print(A)
```

Output:

```
[[1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

Similar questions,

[Multiple ranges of numpy array returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491483/multiple-ranges-of-numpy-array-returned)

[Index multiple, non-adjacent ranges in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188620/index-multiple-non-adjacent-ranges-in-numpy)

Comment: Wow.. unbelievable! Thank u so much! Python seems quite complex. I think Matlab grammar is really excellent.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest just to do it in two lines.

```
A[:4,3:5] = 0
A[8:,3:5] = 0
```

(indices based on your picture)

Comment: Thank u for your answer! I know that method but i want to do it one line.. Can u do this?